# Limit with parameter question

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

> Let $k\in\mathbb{N}_0$. Compute the following limit:
>   $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{\sum_{m=1}^{n}m^{k+\frac{3}{2}}}{n^{k+\frac{5}{2}}}$$

One can rewrite this as $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{n}(\frac{m}{n})^{k+\frac{3}{2}}\cdot\frac{1}{n}$ but now I don't know how I should proceed with this.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Do you know about Riemann integral? If so, you can consider this expression as Riemann sum of the function $f(x)=x^{k+\frac{3}{2}}$.

Comment: @richrow no, I'm afraid I don't, do you know if there is a different approach to this?

Comment: Well, then try to prove the following inequality: $m^{\alpha}<\frac{(m+1)^{\alpha+1}-m^{\alpha+1}}{\alpha+1}<(m+1)^{\alpha}$ where $\alpha=k+\frac{3}{2}$.